How to remove the white space on the edges of an image (Vuetify)?
I've been trying for hours to make an image stretch across the full width of the screen but there's always white space either on both sides or just the left side. Right now it's on both sides
This is the code:
     <v-row>
        <v-col class="pa-0">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img
              src="@/assets/images/digitalsignature.jpg"
              alt="Digital Signature"
              class="full-width-image"
            />
    
            <div class="button-container">
              <v-btn rounded="lg" size="x-large" block class="d-flex align-center justify-center">
                Get started
                <v-icon right>mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </template>
    
    <style scoped>
    .image-container {
      margin-top: 32px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .full-width-image {
    
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      filter: blur(5px);
      object-fit: cover;
    }

I also have a button inside it and need it to be centered in the image. Right now it's fine except that there's a tiny amount of space on the sides
Edit: I found the issue using devtools. In app.vue
 <v-main>
       <v-container fluid>
         <router-view />
       </v-container>
     </v-main>

the v-container has space by default so I set padding to 0px

Give a try to object-fit: cover;? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

There is a lot of layout between your particular component and the actual screen - at the very least html, body, probably container or anything else you could put there. We actually have to look at the whole html as it is rendered by the browser to say "here is your problem". I would advice to render the page and save the resulting html (or look at it by yourself, it's not hard, using devtools), find the offending style and then pinpoint it on the component.
I don't see any obvious problem with the part of code you've posted.
